# Why is response of system same frequency as driving force frequency

Tags: classical-mechanics, fourier-transform, frequency, coupled-oscillators, linear-systems

Super basic question: why does a system (to be definite, perhaps assume a collection of coupled harmonic oscillators) respond (in the steady-state, after transient effects have dissipated) with all members oscillating at the same frequency, albeit with different amplitude and phases. This seems to be a starting assumption for several calculations. Now, I mean it kinda makes sense, but I can't explain it to myself particularly eloquently and perhaps someone can give me an obvious/rigorous explanation.

Comment: Can you give some concrete system and how it's driven? Currently it's not quite clear what you're asking.

Comment: Ok how about a linear chain of identical masses connected by identical springs, where the first one is driven at a constant frequency. I believe one assumes that all members will oscillate at the same frequency as the driving and then with this assumption work out the amplitudes and phases of each member, but I'm asking why we can assume they all oscillate at the same frequency as the driving frequency.

Comment: @Tom  ,but the normal modes of vibrations of coupled oscillators give variety of frequencies- a few may be identical but its usually different....see                                                                                                          <http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/FrancescoHautmann/Cp4p/sl_nm_3_12.pdf>

Comment: *"why we can assume they all oscillate at the same frequency as the driving frequency"* Well, as you can see below this *isn't* an assumption. It is both a experimental observation and a result that comes out of simple models (and out of more complex ones in some part of their parameter space).

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically determine if the physical system is linear; i.e., can it be described by an ordinary differential equation (ODE), or by a system of ODEs.  Most simple mechanical and electronic systems can be modelled this way.

Now take any simple ODE, second order for example, and model the homogeneous ODE with Matlab, for example. Next add a driving function to the right hand side, making it an inhomogeneous ODE; a cosine function would work if your expressions are real, else a complex exponential.

When this system is modeled you will see the driving frequency at work, and the corresponding responses. This example shows how linear systems respond to a driving frequency.  This is why linear algebra and ODEs are often studied together.

If you drive with multiple frequencies you will see additional phenomena appear. If the material has a nonlinear response the situation becomes richer and more complicated.

Comment: Your chain of harmonic oscillators would make a good coupled system to model. Start with one, drive it at one, then two frequencies;  then add one element to the chain, repeat, etc. Then alter the spring constants, one by one, slightly,  and then by larger amounts. A careful and extended study of such a simple system can be very rewarding.

Answer (score 2):

Technically in the absence of dissipation oscillations need not be limited to those of driving frequency, but driving frequency oscillations are always present under driving, and so are the focus of the discussion. If however dissipation is present, then oscillations that are not maintained by the driving input loose energy and die out in time, while the driven ones are supported by the constant energy input of the driving force.

Say your system is described by some set of coordinates summed up in a vector ${\bf u}(t)$, the corresponding driving force is some ${\bf f} e^{i\omega t}$ (this can have just one non-zero component as you suggest) and the dynamics is non-dissipative and of the form
$$
A{\bf u}(t) = {\bf f} e^{i\omega t}
$$
where $A = A\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)$ is a linear differential operator, usually 2nd order. Then the general solution for ${\bf u}(t)$ reads
$$
{\bf u}(t) = {\bf u}_0(t) + {\bf u}_1(t)
$$
where ${\bf u}_0(t)$ is any solution in the absence of driving,
$$
A{\bf u}_0(t) = 0
$$
and ${\bf u}_1(t)$ is some particular solution under driving,
$$
A{\bf u}_1(t) = {\bf f} e^{i\omega t}
$$ 
The former is of oscillatory type, while the latter can be found under the ansatz ${\bf u}_1(t) = {\bf u}^0_1e^{i\omega t}$ and will contribute driven oscillations. So in this case the general solution is a superposition of unperturbed and driven oscillations.

Now say we add the simplest dissipative contribution in the form of an identical friction force on all components, such that the dynamics becomes
$$
A{\bar{\bf u}} + \lambda {\bar{\bf u}} \equiv (A + \lambda){\bar{\bf u}} = {\bf f} e^{i\omega t}
$$
The general solution again accommodates a contribution ${\bar{\bf u}}_0(t)$ from the unperturbed dynamics in the absence of driving, but in this case ${\bar{\bf u}}_0(t)$ must satisfy
$$
(A + \lambda){\bar{\bf u}}_0(t) = 0
$$
and is in general a damped solution of the form
$$
{\bar{\bf u}}_0(t) = {\tilde{\bf u}}_0(t)e^{-\kappa(\lambda) t}
$$
The driven solution on the other hand remains an oscillatory one as before, ${\bar{\bf u}}_1(t) = {\tilde{\bf u}}^0_1e^{i\omega t}$ despite the dissipative term (just plug in ${\bar{\bf u}}_1(t)$ and see how the resulting equation is modified). Hence overall we are left with 
$$
{\bar{\bf u}} = {\tilde{\bf u}}_0(t)e^{-\kappa(\lambda) t} + {\tilde{\bf u}}^0_1e^{i\omega t}\;\; \rightarrow \;\; {\tilde{\bf u}}^0_1e^{i\omega t} \;\;\text{as}\;\;t\rightarrow \infty
$$
The unperturbed oscillations simply die out, only the driven ones persist.

**Note**: Peter Diehr posted his answer while I was typing this, but didn't show on my editor. So lots of overlap.

Comment: Thank you for this insightful answer. Can you comment on the ansatz, as I think it is this assumption that I am having trouble justifying. Why should the solution oscillate at the same frequency as the driving force?

Comment: @Tom Welcome. Formally you can put it like this: whatever trial solution you plug in the left hand side the result must match the driving force on the right. But you'd probably prefer a much more rigorous approach using the Fourier transform of ${\bf u}(t)$, ${\bf u}(t) = \int{d\omega' {\bf u}(\omega')e^{i\omega' t}}$. Components of any other frequency will have to satisfy the unperturbed dynamics, while the one at the driving frequency will match the driving force. The ansatz simply separates the latter for expediency.

Comment: @udrv: I decided to leave out the examples, and just give the reasons;  let the student do the work, and they learn more. ;-)

Comment: @PeterDiehr I can only agree, it's the workout that matters in the end, but it has to have good direction :)

Comment: Ok so I think what you're saying is you plug in an arbitrary function as a fourier integral and if you work through only the frequency component the same as the driving force drops out as non-zero. But I'll work through it and see for myself.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try a more general approach.

All forces are, one way or another, transported by particles at a given velocity. The *strength* of the force at any given time corresponds to the *strength* of the source at the time when it was emitted. If the force at a given point is oscillating, it just means the source was oscillating. And because all known forces do not depend directly on time of travel (they may only decrease by distance), then they must have the same frequency.

Now, if you have a moving source or a moving target, there may be changes in frequency due to the Doppler effect, or other tricky things. In addition, when considering multiple-particle interactions, there may also be complex behaviours leading to changes in frequency.

The next point is the consequence of that force on the studied system. If the system is linear (response proportional to force), then, almost by definition, the response will have the same frequency. The other answers were pretty good on that particular point.

Edit: actually some forces may depend on time of travel. Let's just focus on electromagnetic interaction here.